# vercel build error with using javascript function

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I'm getting a build error like this with vercel,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

with code like this which works in development,

```
{Substances[selectedSubstance]?.map((s) => (
              <Area
                fill="#82ca9d"
                stroke="#82ca9d"
                type="monotone"
                dataKey="concentration"
                data={s.doseDetails}
                name={s.doseTime}
                key={s.doseTime}
              />
            ))}
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's related to that code?

Comment: That's what the build error is saying